# How to perform a linear homography of an image in tensorflow

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, image-processing

I would like to be able to replicate the behaviour of the opencv function `warpPerspective` which takes as input an image and an homography matrix, and projects the image according to the homography matrix (more details here : https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html).

It seems like `tf.contrib.image.sparse_image_warp` should do the job, but I am unable to replicate the behaviour of `warpPerspective`. The output I get is distorted in a non-linear fashion despite the use of the parameter `interpolation_order=1`.

With some further research, I suspect this is due to the fact that `tf.contrib.image.interpolate_spline` does not perform linear interpolation even when its order is 1 but rather uses some RBF kernels.

I can't see a way around this except encoding it with a `dense_image_warp`, but it seems a bit overkill and maybe costly. Does anyone has another solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, here is a solution. it uses the `tf.contrib.image.dense_image_warp` function and is not really pretty, but still, it works :

This first function computes the optical flow needed to perform the homography :

```
    def homography_matrix_to_flow(tf_homography_matrix, im_shape1, im_shape2):
        Y, X = np.meshgrid(range(im_shape1), range(im_shape2))
        Z = np.ones_like(X)
        XYZ = np.stack((X, Y, Z), axis=-1)
        tf_XYZ = tf.constant(XYZ.astype("float64"))
        tf_XYZ = tf_XYZ[tf.newaxis,:,:, :, tf.newaxis]

        tf_homography_matrix = tf.tile(tf_homography_matrix[tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis], (1, im_shape2, im_shape1, 1, 1))
        tf_unnormalized_transformed_XYZ = tf.matmul(tf_homography_matrix, tf_XYZ, transpose_b=False)
        tf_transformed_XYZ = tf_unnormalized_transformed_XYZ / tf_unnormalized_transformed_XYZ[:,:,:, -1][:,:,:, tf.newaxis]
        flow = -tf.squeeze(tf_transformed_XYZ-tf_XYZ)[..., :2]

        return flow
```

Then, it used to warp the original image to the distorted image.

There is one trick : due to how the `tf.contrib.image.dense_image_warp` function works, you need to pass the inverse of the homography matrix to find the correct optical flow to use.

```
        homography_matrix = np.array([[-4.86219067e-01, -2.20871298e+00,  4.08214879e+02],
        [-1.02940133e-01, -5.60378659e+00,  3.87573763e+02],
        [-1.35051362e-04, -6.59600583e-03,  2.91244998e-01]])

        inv_homography_matrix = np.linalg.inv(homography_matrix)

        tf_inv_homography_matrix = tf.constant(inv_homography_matrix)[tf.newaxis]
        flow = homography_matrix_to_flow(tf_inv_homography_matrix, img.shape[1], img.shape[2])[tf.newaxis]
        flow =tf.tile(flow, (self.bs, 1,1,1))
        image_warped = tf.contrib.image.dense_image_warp(tf.transpose(img, (0,2,1,3)), flow)
        image_warped = tf.transpose(image_warped, (0,2,1,3))
```

I still hope to find a better answer (one which does not have to compute a whole tensor of flow), therefore, I leave the question unanswered for now.